# How can my Flex code know if every people in my video chat room can use rtmfp?

Tags: apache-flex, logic, rtmp, flash-media-server, rtmfp

I have created a video chat room by FMS/Flex. what I need to do is:

1. If everybody in one chat room can use rtmfp, we go with rtmfp
2. if anybody in the chat room disabled his rtmfp, we go with rtmp.

Now I need to create a logic to decide if everybody can use rtmfp between each other, Is there a good way to do so?

Answer (score 1):

The clients should connect to FMS first, then call all clients to start connect to the peer.
When a client connected successfully, or the connection was unsuccessful to the peer, report it to FMS. If FMS has as many "positive" answers as the clients length, all of the clients could connect to the peer. If not, send a command to the clients, disconnect them from the peer, and connect all of the clients to an rtmp chatroom.

Hope this helps.

Cheers

Tamas

Comment: Thanks, Tamas, it sounds reasonable, I will take a try